# How to load new csv files in react without auto refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, csv, flask

I am a newbie with react and I am creating an application that calls some flask api to build new csv files which will be used in the end by reacting to build a new graph, but since the file changes on each request the page refresh by itself.. which is not good at all
can anyone propose a solution?

```
const csvSource='../Parent_children.csv'
componentWillMount() {
 treeUtil.parseCSV(csvSource)
 .then((data) => {
 this.setState({data })
 console.log('This is the new data for the tree',data)
 })
 .catch((err) => console.error(err));
 }
 render() {
 return (
 <Col md={8} xl={12}>
                    <Card className='Recent-Users'>
                        <Card.Header>
                            <Card.Title as='h5'>Decision Tree </Card.Title>
                            <div id="treeWrapper" style={{width: '200',height:'50em'}} ref={tc => (this.treeContainer = tc)}> 
<div> <h4> {this.state.Message}</h4></div>
    <Tree
      data={this.state.data}
      orientation={'horizontal'}
      nodeSvgShape={svgSquare}          
  
      translate={{
        x:0,
        y: 100
      }}
      nodeSize={{
        x: 900,
        y: 80
      }}
      textLayout={{
        textAnchor: 'middle',
        x:"60",
        y:"-10"
      }}
     separation={{siblings :1.5, nonSiblings: 2}} 
     transitionDuration='0'
            />
  </div>
                        </Card.Header>

                        
                    </Card>
                </Col>
   )}
```

Comment: could you post the whole component where you're using it?

Comment: I have edited the post